# How to wait until a button a delegate is called

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I want to create an function that will display a UIActionSheet, wait till user press a button and then return the button pressed

```
@interface UIActionSheetHandler () <UIActionSheetDelegate>

@end
@implementation UIActionSheetHandler


-(NSInteger) buttonIndexWithMessage:(NSString *) title andArrayOfOptions:(NSArray *) options
{

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    for (NSString * strOption in options) {
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:strOption];
    }

    [actionSheet showInView:[BGMDApplicationsPointers window]];

    //Wait till delegate is called.
    return 0;//I want to return buttonIndex here.
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //What should I put it here
}
@end
```

How do I make //Wait till delegate is called to wait? Oh ya, I do not want the main thread to wait but I think I can solve that one.

Comment: And why do you want to do that ? Button index will be passed when the button is pressed

Comment: Because I already have a function that wait for button index. It's easier to program on that style.

Comment: Mind if I disagree :) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works

```
self.operation=[NSOperationQueue new]; //These four line is necessary to suspend the whole thread.
self.operation.suspended=true; //Okay make t
[self.operation addOperationWithBlock:^{}];
[self.operation waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];//Don't get out of the function till user act.
```

Then at delegate

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    self.buttonIndex=buttonIndex;
    self.operation.suspended=false;
}
```

Note: I am still looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I have tried to use your above code.But my main thread permanently stopped for waiting a delegate function. My delegate function is for GCDAsyncSocket.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you misunderstood the delegate concept. Do cannot return the button pressed from `buttonIndexWithMessage:andArrayOfOptions:`

As a matter of fact, the UIActionSheet will not even be visible at that point in time.

Once the button is pressed the UIActionSheet will invoke the `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` Method of your delegate.

So, where you put in `//What should I put it here there` you are handed over the index of the button that has been pressed. There you can react on the button pressed accordingly. 
e.g.:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog (@"Button pressed with index: %d", buttonIndex); 
}
```

Comment: I am well aware of delegate concept. I just want to use it differently.

Comment: Ah. Then go ahead and let us know the results. You may want to implement your own alert view then.